# ASP.NET Windows Authentication - Logging Off

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET application using Windows Authentication.
At the moment the only way for a user to log-off the application is to close the browser (it is a pain because closing the tab itself is not enough).

I would like to have a log-off button so make it easier to log-in as a different user.

Is it possible at all (IE and/or Firefox)?

Thanks.

Comment: Then post a link to the dupe.  I don't see it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Windows Authentication logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067263/asp-net-windows-authentication-logout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

[ASP.NET Windows Authentication logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067263/asp-net-windows-authentication-logout)

Answer (score 0):

You should use forms auth if you want to show good ui login, logout forms.
Via IIS you can verify ldap users.