# log out asp.net user through sql?

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

Can I force a log out through SQL for asp.net membership account?

Comment: I added 'forms-authentication' tag since it was stated that was the auth mode in a comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No record of currently logged in users are stored in Forms Authentication mode so it would be impossible to log out a user by some SQL execution alone.

Note that a data store like SQL is only used during the actual credential authentication step of the Forms Authentication lifetime:

[Forms authentication control flow http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa480476.formsauth(en-us,MSDN.10).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa480476.formsauth(en-us,MSDN.10).gif)

Forms Authentication generally utilizes client-side cookies to handle currently logged in users.

Source: [Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For forms authentication you can use:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

If you are trying to do this through Windows authentication see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067263/asp-net-windows-authentication-logout).

Comment: I specifically asked for SQL.

Comment: Not sure I understand than, what do you mean through SQL. What Authentication are you using? Forms, Windows, or Passport?

Comment: I am using Forms Authentication.  But I am trying to log someone out inside of my SQL code, but that seems impossible.