# Change user with authentication windows

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In web.config, I am using:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

to connect my user. The authentication is automatic. But sometimes, I need to change the user account.

How can I open the authentication window of my web browser on a button click?

Comment: You could use impersonation, check this http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306158

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another S.O topic show that you have to use forms authentification to be able to logout...

See [the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067263/asp-net-windows-authentication-logout)