# IIS Windows Authentication - Change User - issue with IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, iis-8.5

**Note: The below issue only occurs in IE 11, and works fine with Chrome**

In our intranet we are setup to use purely windows authentication for all our web applications. The setup consists of a home page web app, and few other web applications linked from the home page, each application and home page are in separate application pools. We have implemented **Change User** functionality using the standard 401 redirects as mentioned at ['Login as another user' MVC 4 Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25672345).

The current hosting server is Windows Server 2008 R2 and we are doing our due diligence for migrating to Windows Server 2012 R2.

During testing we found that the **Change User** functionality works fine on the home page, but when accessing any other app the logged in user returns back to the original logged in user. The links are opened in a new tab by using _target='blank' from the home page.

Same application hosted on Windows 2008 R2 functions as expected and the **Changed User** is reflected on the other web applications as well.

I have tried googling without any matching experience, is this a known issue and are there any workarounds to fix the same?

Sample setup and output:

**Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5)**

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ Time-Step ║     Url-Location     ║     Current-User      ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║         1 ║ /HomePage            ║ MyDomain\OriginalUser ║
║         2 ║ /HomePage/ChangeUser ║ MyDomain\NewUser      ║
║         3 ║ /MyApp               ║ MyDomain\NewUser      ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

**Windows Server 2012 R2 (IIS 8.5)**

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ Time-Step ║     Url-Location     ║     Current-User      ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║         1 ║ /HomePage            ║ MyDomain\OriginalUser ║
║         2 ║ /HomePage/ChangeUser ║ MyDomain\NewUser      ║
║         3 ║ /MyApp               ║ MyDomain\OriginalUser ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

The current user information is accessed using [User.Identity.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.name(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The order of the providers in Windows authentication matters. The issue was solved once we moved the NTLM above Negotiate in the providers list.