# Impersonate User with Forms Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, impersonation

I am using Forms Authorization to login to my web application against the active directory, what I am trying to do is when the user logins, impersonate that user. But I am running into a few problems, when I enable impersonate either via IIS or web.config I get a 500 error, here is that section of my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
<identity impersonate="true" />
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

If I set my credentials in the identity element it works without adjusting my IIS:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\username" password="password" />
```

Here is my authorization in my IIS, this is what its currently set too:

[image]

If I disable Anonymous and enable impersonation, I get a 500 error.

What am I doing wrong and how do I get Forms Authentication to work with Impersonation.

Here is my login Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Login model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

        return View(model);
    }

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

    return View(model);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I got passed the 500 error via `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />`, but the impersonate is still not working unless I set the credentials. Is there away I can set the credentials of the person logging in?

**UPDATE**

When I run this code, I can see that it is populated with the correct username and impersonate is set to true, what am I doing wrong?

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

Comment: What is the content of the HTTP 500 error? That sounds important and relevant.

Comment: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: This happens if I goto any page in the web application

Comment: You need to enable detailed HTTP 500 error messages. Do you have error-logging configured?

Comment: I got passed the 500 error via <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />, but the impersonate is still not working unless I set the credentials. Is there away I can set the credentials of the person logging in?

Comment: This has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066275/impersonate-using-forms-authentication) years ago.

Comment: what is the error you are getting after having disabled `validateIntegratedModeConfiguration`?

Comment: *Is there away I can set the credentials of the person logging in* → No, without using user's password, you cannot do impersonation.

Answer (score 3):

> Focusing on this part: *What I am trying to do is when the user logins, impersonate that user.*

What you are looking for is called delegation.

Delegation without using username and password of the user relies on Integrated **Windows Authentication**. You cannot achieve it using **Forms Authentication** unless use username and password of the user and do [protocol transition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649317(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

For learning purpose, [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066275/impersonate-using-forms-authentication) shows an example of how you can do it in code by using the username and password which you receive from login page.

I know this may be disappointing, but if you need delegation, you should rely on Windows Authentication and configure browser, IIS and ASP.NET application. To see a complete guide take a look at [How to configure an ASP.NET application for a delegation scenario](https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/810572/how-to-configure-an-asp-net-application-for-a-delegation-scenario).

This is not a complete guide of the configurations, however shows you the most important configurations:

- **Setup browser** : To setup browser, for IE, you need to check *Enable Windows Integrated Authentication* in *Advanced* tab of *Internet Options*.
- **Setup IIS** : To setup IIS, you need to disable all authentications on IIS including *Anonymous Authentication* and just enable *Windows Authentication*.
- **Setup ASP.NET Application**: In the web.config you need to set `<authentication mode="Windows" />` and also set `<identity impersonate="true" />` and also `<allow users="*" /><deny users="?" />`